# How to get TFS Build quality in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I need powershell script to get Build quality (Released or Rejected or Trial build) of a successful build.

Tried with the following script: Issue is that If I have more than 4-5 release builds, How can I get the list of the builds???? The script below gives me the immeadiate on and the next on changing the values of MaxBuildsPerDefinition=2 or 3. I need to get all the release candidate builds.

```
[string] $tfsLocation = "http://serverURL/tfs"
[string] $projectName = "ProjectName"
[string] $buildDefinitionName = "BuildDefinition"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll"
$tfsUri = New-object Uri($tfsLocation)
$teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsUri)
$service = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([Type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer")
$spec = $service.CreateBuildDetailSpec($projectName, $buildDefinitionName)
$spec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 2
$spec.QueryOrder = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildQueryOrder]::FinishTimeDescending
$results = $service.QueryBuilds($spec)

if ($results.Builds.Length -eq 2) 
{
   Write-Host $results.Builds[0].Quality
if ($results.Builds[0].Quality = "Released")
{
  <<My Script Here>>

} else { 
<<My Script Here>>
}
} else { 

Write-Error "No builds found." 
}
```

Comment: sounds like a good idea. What have you tried so we can assist you with it. If you are not sure how to post your script. Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added my trial script above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-list-of-builds) to retrieve the Build quality of a successful build. You can specify the filters based on your requirement accordingly. Also you can export the build list to a **.CSV** file.

```
$collectionurl = "http://serverURL/tfs"
$projectName= "ProjectNname"
$BuildDefinitionId = "74"    
$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/$projectName/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&definitions=$BuildDefinitionId&statusFilter=completed&resultFilter=succeeded"    # Set the filter based on your requirements.        
$builds = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).value|where({$_.quality -in 'Released', 'Rejected','Trial'})  # filter the builds which have quality elements.

    $BuildResults = @()

    foreach($build in $builds){

        $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
              "BuildDefinition" = $build.definition.name
              "BuildId" = $build.id
              "BuildNumber" = $build.buildNumber
              "status" = $build.status
              "result" = $build.result
              "BuildQuality" = $build.quality
              "finishTime" = $build.finishTime
              "sourceBranch" = $build.sourceBranch
            } 

        $BuildResults += $customObject      
    }

    $BuildResults | Select `
                    BuildDefinition,
                    BuildId, 
                    BuildNumber, 
                    status,
                    result,
                    BuildQuality,
                    finishTime,
                    sourceBranch #|export-csv -Path E:\$projectName-Build.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Perfect. That helps me a lot. Thank you

Comment: Works flawlessly!! thnx.